# Sending trace data to OpenZIpkin using Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

**Update**: I have pushed the code to [my repo](https://github.com/massenz/zipkindemo) so people can take a look there to see what may be going wrong.

**Edit**: I'm almost sure it's the client code NOT POSTing any stats to the server, but neither guides below explain how should this be enabled: is there a configuration setting that I am missing?

I have been following the quick starts on both [OpenZipkin](http://zipkin.io/pages/quickstart) and [Spring Sleuth](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/): I have a running Zipkin server from [docker-zipkin](https://github.com/openzipkin/docker-zipkin) using the `docker-compose` and Cassandra as the backend:

```
$ d ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                               NAMES
5ca0f0b29900        openzipkin/zipkin:1.12.1             "/bin/sh -c 'test -n "   14 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:9410-9411->9410-9411/tcp                                                    zipkin
7b243a0b61e3        openzipkin/zipkin-dependencies       "crond -f"               14 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes                                                                                            dependencies
e2e047fb3851        openzipkin/zipkin-cassandra:1.12.1   "/bin/sh -c /usr/loca"   14 minutes ago      Up 8 minutes        7000-7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, 9160/tcp   cassandra
```

I have created and run the [Spring Sleuth sample app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/tree/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-sample-zipkin) and it seems to be configured correctly to trace calls:

```
# application.properties)
server.port = 9099
spring.application.name = zipkin-demo
spring.zipkin.baseUrl = http://localhost:9411/
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage = 1.0
```

The logs seem to show that the traces ought to be logged:

```
2016-10-04 15:20:02.115  INFO [zipkin-demo,c6e06ff47bddaf4d,f7437cf1c7089522,true] 70899 --- [nio-9099-exec-3] com.apple.its.api.ApiController          : Forwarding to http://localhost:8088/api/v1/hello
2016-10-04 15:20:02.709  INFO [zipkin-demo,de3c25ea46e8b010,f7e6017757f0ce5e,true] 70899 --- [nio-9099-exec-4] com.apple.its.api.ApiController          : Forwarding to http://localhost:8088/api/v1/hello
2016-10-04 15:20:06.480  INFO [zipkin-demo,4c9fdeaab69b79b4,1dc8b9b7ce5c6fa5,true] 70899 --- [nio-9099-exec-5] com.apple.its.api.ApiController          : Sleeping for [278] millis
2016-10-04 15:20:08.833  INFO [zipkin-demo,2eb26be1a6867e5,b566753eb137026,true] 70899 --- [nio-9099-exec-8] com.apple.its.api.ApiController          : Sleeping for [467] millis
2016-10-04 15:20:10.608  INFO [zipkin-demo,eec83e7fc4ea9c9d,c88723b29ca4335c,true] 70899 --- [nio-9099-exec-1] com.apple.its.api.ApiController          : Sleeping for [20] millis
2016-10-04 15:20:12.035  INFO [zipkin-demo,63259dd1bac357e9,5cf013d16bb1ee98,true] 70899 --- [nio-9099-exec-4] com.apple.its.api.ApiController          : Sleeping for [22] millis
```

However, the UI does not show any traces at all, no matter what I do.
The weird thing is that the `localhost:9411/trace` does show a bunch of traces (they seem to be mostly from Zipkin itself) but there are none from the `zipkin-demo` app.

I believe this due to the demo app not sending the traces to the host, but I'm just using [Spring's example app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/tree/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples), so what can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your application calling another one? AFAIR you need at least 2 to sketch a graph

Comment: The app is siimply the "getting started" app from Spring Sleuth; however, as you can see in the logs, the traces are being generated.  What's missing, I believe, is the sending to the Zipkin server.

Comment: Have you set the sampler percentage to 1.0 or added an AlwaysSampler ?

Comment: Yes - I did it [like this](https://github.com/massenz/zipkindemo/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/apple/its/ZipkinDemoApplication.java#L27) following an example, but it would be great to know whether that was The Right Way.

Comment: Typically the right way is to add the sample percentage value to 1.0 . AlwaysSampler makes sense for tests. I'm a little confused now - do we stil have a problem or not? Is it working or is there a bug?

Comment: well, yes, *I* still have a problem :) *no* traces are sent to the server: I'm almost sure no POST is made from the application - I don't think has anything at all to do with AlwaysSampler or the percentage (FWIW, I had already tried all possible variations on this).  The server does not receive any traces at all, and it's not clear at all from the documentation, what needs to be done application-side to get Spring Sleuth to push them.

Comment: Can you post your sample somewhere please?

Comment: It's the first line of the question :) ["my repo"](https://github.com/massenz/zipkindemo)  
the actual URL: https://github.com/massenz/zipkindemo

Comment: this config worked for me in 1 of my application:
spring.zipkin.baseUrl = http://localhost:9411/
spring.sleuth.enabled = true
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage = 1.0
Enabling property might do the trick!

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not mistaken (and I guess I'm not) no wonder that you're not sending the Spans to Zipkin cause you didn't add the Zipkin dependency. Check the *Sleuth with Zipkin via HTTP* section of the docs: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html .

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.RELEASE"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This config worked for me in 1 of my application:

```
  spring.zipkin.baseUrl = localhost:9411 
  spring.sleuth.enabled = true 
  spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage = 1.0
```

Enabling property might do the trick!

Comment: `spring.zipkin.baseUrl = localhost:9411`   and `spring.sleuth.enabled = true ` are defaults so you don't have to set them. The default for `percentage` is `0.1` so every tenth trace is sent to Zipkin. Also you have to add the `Zipkin` starter to send spans to Zipkin otherwise it doesn't matter what your percentage is.